# Trying to bind column headers to properties in my C# code

Tags: xaml

I currently have:

```
<Window x:Class="Client_SCM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client_SCM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Swords Call Monitor 2.0" Height="350" Width="474">

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Margin="5"
      ShowGridLines="True">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="5"
              AlternatingRowBackground="Aqua" Loaded="dataGrid_Loaded" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>

</Grid>
```

And I'm trying to implement something like this into it:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WhateverIWantToDisplay}" >
```

```
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo}" Value="1">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </DataTrigger>

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo}" Value="2">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </DataTrigger>

    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo}" Value="2">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </DataTrigger>

  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The error I'm getting is "The property 'Content' can only be set once".

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Header` instead of `Binding` on your `DataGridTextColumn`.

```
<Window x:Class="Client_SCM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client_SCM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Swords Call Monitor 2.0" Height="350" Width="474">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" ShowGridLines="True">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="Aqua" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding WhateverIWantToDisplay}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```